# How to scroll in insert mode?

Tags: vim

Is there a default key for scrolling in insert mode? I know that I could just

```
:imap <F5> <ESC><C-e>a
:imap <F6> <ESC><C-y>a
```

but I'm wondering if there's any key binding there by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For completeness, there are two dedicated commands for scrolling in insert mode, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>. They are probably the proper ones to map.

See the documentation here: `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-E`.

In normal mode <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> do the same thing, I use them quite often.

Answer (score 5):

In `insert mode`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, then type <kbd>zz</kbd>.
It'll set current line in the middle of the screen.

Actually, you can type any command.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about ^o. Then I can just go with ^o^e and ^o^y.